# On-prem Postgresql DB to Snowflake Data Pipeline

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pipeline

I am tasked with building a data pipeline from an on-prem Postgresql DB that is leveraged to manage my OLTP transactions to Snowflake on Azure and I am busting my brain on choosing a couple of options to POC as the most cost-efficient and optimal data pipeline. The use case is that I will be supporting reporting and analytics so there is no real need for a real-time solution.

My thoughts are in terms of pipeline options are:

1. Postgresql DB --> ADF (run every 15 mins) --> Azure Blob --> External tables --> Snowflake Task / Stored Procs (transformation hourly) --> Conformed --> Modeled tables
2. Postgresql DB --> ADF (run every 15 mins) --> Azure Blob --> Snowflake task / copy into --> Snowflake Raw tables --> Snowflake Task / Stored Procs (transformation hourly) --> Conformed --> Modeled tables

My thought is that the Snowflake external table option would be more cost effective as I will not be copying data from the blob to Snowflake.

Additionally, what options do I have for connecting my pipeline that ingests data from source to azure blob to my pipeline that runs to transform the data into my final modeled tables?

Comment: Snowflake storage is cheap, unless you have a requirement or mandate to use Azure Blob, why do you include it? Load from Postgres to Snowflake directly to Raw tables

Comment: as @demircioglu said, there is no reason to use Blob as an intermediate, but if you choose to go that direction, this is not a good use of external tables.  Highly recommend a COPY INTO route.